# Forefront TMG and IIS on one internet gateway server

Tags: iis, isa-server, microsoft-forefront, web

I have two servers in a datacenter.

One is IIS and another is SQL Server machine. I'd like to install Forefront on a gateway server to make use of "smart" web site publishing and VPN that come with Forefront, but want SQL Server to remain an RDBMS machine.

If I install Forefront on an internet-facing IIS-enabled machine, will it strill be able to work as a web server as well? Specifically, will I be able to publish web site from IIS on this very same host perhaps through local IP's on internal NIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why it wouldn't work, but it's not recommended practise. Ideally a TMG server (like ISA before it) should be used for TMG and nothing more, with the exception of the Exchange Edge Transport Role with Forefront Protection for Exchange.